# How to use React.forwardRef() in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-ref

I am using `refs` for access child component

```
<MyComponent
   ref='_my_refs'
   ...
/>
```

and call them

```
this.refs._my_refs.scrollToTop();
```

I get the error below

> Warning: Function components cannot be given refs. Attempts to access this ref will fail. Did you mean to use React.forwardRef()?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need to wrap `MyComponent` around [`React.forwardRef()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactforwardref)

e.g.

```
const MyComponent = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
    return (
        <View ref={ref}> // using the ref
            // your component 
        </View>
})
```

Also, `ref='_my_refs'` doesn't work because it's a [legacy ref](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactforwardref), you should use [`React.createRef()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactcreateref) for class components or [`useRef`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref) for functional component.
You can check for more details in the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html).

e.g.

```
class ParentComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this._my_refs = React.createRef();
    }

    render(){
        return (
            // ...
            <MyComponent
                ref={this._my_refs}
                ...
            />
        )
    }
}
```

OR

```
const ParentComponent = props => {
    const myRef = React.useRef()    
    return (
        // ...
        <MyComponent
            ref={myRef}
            ...
        />
    )
}
```

If you pass a `ref` to a functional component and it isn't wrapped around `React.forwardRef`, it will give you the error

> Warning: Function components cannot be given refs. Attempts to access this ref will fail. Did you mean to use React.forwardRef()?

And this means `MyComponent` is a functional component and isn't wrapped around `React.forwardRef`.

Comment: Can you help me what to do if the child component is a class type. e.g. `class MyComponent extends React.PureComponent`

Comment: @MahdiBashirpour yes, but you need to show how is the component inside. And your know you are using ref the wrong way right? Did you see that you can't pass a string to ref? Maybe that is the problem

Comment: Looks like we get the ref on View. How do we select a child, let's say a TextInput, inside View? ref.current.<what_comes_here?>